# SQL in Visual Studio 2010 & LINQ

Tags: sql, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2010, version-control

I'm working on a project which relies on the presence of a number of tables, views and stored procedures. Until now I have built these all in SQL Server Management Studio.

Now I would like to continue to work on them inside of Visual Studio. This will provide the benefit of version control (along with a number of other benefits hopefully).

I have added a new project to my solution and started working on one of the views. When I tried to build the solution it failed as the new project didn't have a server/database associated: Error      1      SQL03006: View: [dbo].[vw_Test2] has an unresolved reference to object [EV870_ACCT_MASTER].

I was able to overcome this by 
-creating a dbschema dump using vsdbcmd.exe
-adding the dbschema dump as a reference to my database project

Is this the correct approach?

Now i can see the schema (tables, views, sprocs etc) in the Schema view (I had to enable display of "external elements") and the error message has gone away. Note: I had to reference like: [$(SQLDatabase)].[dbo].[EV870_ACCT_MASTER]

Now I want to know how I can work with these objects that i've scripted. I don't know how to use the new tables, views, sprocs etc (I want to use LINQ). Do i have to run the scripts first? How then if they are "CREATE OBJECT" scripts, will they run in future (presumably they'd fail as the object already exists in the database). Will my project/solution know which objects need updating and update them?

Ultimately want to take it a lot further- my aim is that the solution will be portable and a the server/database will be configurables. Then my tables, views and stored procedures will be created or amended if they don't exist or are out of date. Is this possible?

When I then start working with the views etc using LINQ I want those server/database references to remain dynamic?

I know there are quite a few questions in there but i'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction- there doesn't seem to be much useful documentation online (or that i've stumbled across so far).

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I work (and the last place I worked) we distribute the sql scripts to create the database along with the app.  In sql a version number is stored and when the app is run it checks to see if its version is newer than the number stored in the database.  If so then it knows it may need to run some new sql scripts in case there were any schema changes.  When this happens, we just run through all the scripts because they are written in a way that running them multiple times won't hurt anything... this way we don't have to worry about tracking which scripts are the new ones.  Just check the version number and that's it.

As far as working with this stuff in Visual Studio instead of Management studio, I'm not sure why anyone would want to do that.  Depending on what you use for source control you may be able to get hooks for Management Studio, but even if not that doesn't stop you from keeping your sql scripts in source control.  And I wouldn't switch from working with my sql files in management studio to visual studio for the benefit of having built in source control any day.

Comment: That is, for the benefit of having built in source control 'hooks'.  You should absolutely keep your sql files in source control, even if you have to do it manually which is not such a big deal once you get used to it.

Comment: That makes sense but then presumably you have to code that all yourself? If visual studio is capable of doing it for me it seems crazy to re-invent the wheel. 
Your point about version control seems valid, but again i don't really want to get into having to separately check-out/in my sql scripts and project/solution.

Comment: @LeeTickett Not sure I follow you on the part about having to code schema yourself.  Management Studio has a GUI for creating schema, and you can right click on the objects in the object explorer and have it automatically generate the scripts for you.

And what are you using for source control?

Comment: Most source control systems have software you can download to take advantage of the hooks through the windows eplorer window.  So it's just a matter of right clicking on the folder that contains all your sql files and committing your changes... nothing to it.

Comment: I was referring to coding the routines to check which database version you are running then running relevant db upgrade scripts.
I'm using SVN (visual SVN server with tortoise client and ankhsvn visual studio plugin).

Comment: Hmm... I guess I wasn't aware of any features in Visual Studio to check which db version you're running, but the code we use to do that is pretty simple and, as I said before, I would write that code over again 3 times to be able to use management studio to do my db work in instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: What benefits do you feel coding in management studio provides? I got the impression that coding in visual studio is pretty much identical (with intelli-sense etc) but with the added bonus of being inside vs and having access to the additional tools etc

Comment: @LeeTickett Super late response I know, but one big advantage to me is that I like to have sql open in a separate window on my second monitor.  And I assume that there are things I can do in Management studio that aren't available in VS but I don't really use it in VS so maybe I'm wrong.  Also, during the very limited time I did spend using it from VS though, I remember feeling like it was kind of laggy.  I imagine they've fixed that by now though.